# How can I create a custom control 'MyThumb' which inherit from Thumb, and at the same time, user can't set MyThumb's Width and Heitht?

Tags: wpf, xaml, controls

I want to create a customer element which inherit from Thumb which I call it "MyThumb".

I want MyThumb has no Width and Height property, which means user can't set its Width or Height through XAML or code. Instead, I want to provide a "Length" property which means this control's width and height are all equal Length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the API of the base class by removing the properties, but you could for example override the metadata for the `Width` and `Height` properties and provide a `CoerceValueCallback` that prevents the property from being set to a custom value:

```
public class MyThumb : Thumb
{
    private const double DefaultWidth = 100.0;
    public MyThumb()
    {
        WidthProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyThumb),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DefaultWidth) { CoerceValueCallback = new CoerceValueCallback(OnWidthCoerced) });
    }

    private object OnWidthCoerced(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        return DefaultWidth;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you may throw an `InvalidOperationException`.